# Paramiko stuck on for loop

Tags: python, exception, paramiko

I need to perform a remote software update for a Linux device.
I'm able to upload via SSH and SFTP to /tmp/ folder the .bin file and perform the sysupgrade.

I want to do this on multiple device, so I added a for loop in order to do it.

But, when I run the ssh.exec_command("sysupgrade /tmp/myfile.bin"), something stucks.
Here's my code:

```
import paramiko

# paths to file
local_path="C:/Users/Desktop/myfile.bin"
remote_path="/tmp/myfile.bin"

# IP
ip_list = ["my_ip_1","my_ip_2"]
password_list=["passw_1","passw_2"]

#Start SSH
ssh = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# loop for IP and password
for i,n in zip(ip_list,password_list):
    print(i,n)

try:
    print("Open session in: " + i + "...")
    ssh.connect(i, username='root', password=n)
except paramiko.SSHException:
    print("Connection Failed")
    quit()

# Upload file to /tmp/
print("Uploading file to " + str(i) + " in /tmp/...")
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put(local_path, remote_path)

try:
    # Here something stucks
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sysupgrade /tmp/myfile.bin", timeout=30)
    sysupgrade_response=stdout.readlines()
    print(sysupgrade_response)
    sftp.close()
    ssh.close()
except paramiko.SSHException:
    print("Continue with others IP in list...")
    sftp.close()
    ssh.close()
    continue


sftp.close()
ssh.close()

print("\n\n***********************End execution***********************\n\n")
```

This is the errors I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 699, 
in  recv
out = self.in_buffer.read(nbytes, self.timeout)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\paramiko\buffered_pipe.py",
line 164, in read
raise PipeTimeout()
paramiko.buffered_pipe.PipeTimeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Python Scripts\myscript.py", line 73, in <module>
sysupgrade_response=stdout.readlines()
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\paramiko\file.py", line 349, 
in  readlines
line = self.readline()
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\paramiko\file.py", line 291, 
in readline
new_data = self._read(n)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 1361, 
in _read
return self.channel.recv(size)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 701,
in recv
raise socket.timeout()
```

After the "sysupgrade" command, I would like to close the connection with the first ip in the list ( or handling some errors ) and go on with the for loop and connect to the second ip in the list.

Hope is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `sysupgrade` restarts the machine or at least the SSH server or networking.

I would guess that if you execute `sysupgrade` in your SSH client, it will also lose the connection, won't it?

Comment: Yes, my device will restart; and I thought that the paramiko.SSHException: will get the disconnection but this not happens.
so I added a timeout=30 on the exec_command and I think this is why I got the "raise socket.timeout()"

Comment: Does your SSH client disconnect immediately after you execute the `sysupgrade`?

Comment: I'm also connected via WINscp to the ssh client, and when the python script runs the sysupgrade command WINscp gets immediately a disconnection error from the client.
Then I get some output from the stdout.readline and then the timeout triggers some exceptions.
I would like to handle this and continue with the for loop connecting to the other clients.

Comment: That's not really an answer to my question.

Comment: No,the SSH client does not disconnect immediately after the sysupgrade

Comment: OK, so that kind of answers your question, doesn't it?